# Multiplos componentes no Vue.use

Tags: vue.js

Estou usando estes componentes em meu código

```
Vue.use(Toaster, {timeout: 5000})
Vue.use(VueAlert)
Vue.use(VueSweetAlert)
```

Existe algum jeito de eu ligar estes três em apenas um `Vue.use` ?

Algo desse tipo (*incorreto*)

```
Vue.use([
         { Toaster, {timeout: 5000} },
         { VueAlert },
         { VueSweetAlert }
        ])
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Posso estar enganado, mas eu acho que não é possivel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repare no método nativo

```
/* @flow */

import { toArray } from '../util/index'

export function initUse (Vue: GlobalAPI) {
  Vue.use = function (plugin: Function | Object) {
const installedPlugins = (this._installedPlugins || (this._installedPlugins = []))
```

`Vue.use` só recebe um objeto ou uma função, não é possível passar múltiplos objetos :/